# Set 3 x 3 Image Matrix of Pictures above checkbox

Tags: php, html, css

[image: there is not a real order for the pics]Post.blade.php

```
@section('title', 'Forecast API')
<style>
    .dcontainer {
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
        height: 2150px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .dcheckbox {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        right: 0px;
    }
</style>

@section('sidebar')
@parent
<br>
<p>Placeholder</p>
@endsection

@section('content')
<br>
<br>


<div>
    <div>
        <div>

            <form role="form" method="post" action="{{action('DataController@postRequest')}}">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label><font size="12">Antragssteller:</label></font>


                            <select name="claimanttype" size="4">
                                <option>KFZ-Fahrer</option>
                                <option>Motorradfahrer</option>
                                <option>Radfahrer</option>
                                <option>Fußgänger</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <br>


                        <label><font size="12">Alter:</label></font>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="(...)" required min="0" max="122" name="age" style="height:50px;font-size:14pt"/>
                    </div>
                    <br>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label><font size="12">Postleitzahl:</label></font>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="PLZ" required min="10000" max="99999" name="zipcode" style="height:50px;font-size:14pt" />
                    </div>

                    <div>

                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="" name="mcmax" id="mcmax" />
                    </div>
                    <br>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label><font size="12">Diagnosen:</label></font>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div class="dcontainer">
                            <img src="{{asset('img/HWS_Distorsion.png')}}" alt="KI Portfolio" width="150" height="150">
                            <br>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" class="postreq" value="1" name="icdcount" id="s13_4_only">HWS-Distorsion<strong>(S13.4)</strong></label>
                        </div>



                        <div class="dcontainer">

                            <img src="{{asset('img/MultipleRippenfraktur.png')}}" alt="KI Portfolio" width="150" height="150">
                            <br>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" class="postreq" value="3" name="icdcount">Multiple Rippenfraktur<strong>(S22.4)</strong> </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="dcontainer">
                            <img src="{{asset('img/Handgelenksprellung.png')}}" alt="KI Portfolio" width="150" height="150">
                            <br>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" class="postreq" value="2" name="icdcount">Thoraxprellung <strong>(S22.4)</strong> </label>
                        </div>



                        <!-- <label><input type="checkbox" class="postreq" value="3" name="icdcount"> Multiple Rippenfraktur <strong>(S22.4)</strong> </label><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/119/119044.svg" width="150" height="150">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" class="postreq" value="2" name="icdcount"> Thoraxprellung <strong>(S20.2)</strong></label><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/119/119044.svg" width="150" height="150"> -->


                        <div class="dcontainer">
                            <img src="{{asset('img/Schädel-Hirn-Trauma.png')}}" alt="KI Portfolio" width="150" height="150">
                            <br>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" class="postreq" value="2" name="icdcount">Schädel-Hirn-Trauma<strong> (S20.2)</strong></label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="dcontainer">
                            <img src="{{asset('img/Handgelenksprellung.png')}}" alt="KI Portfolio" width="150" height="150">
                            <br>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" class="postreq" value="1" name="icdcount"> Handgelenksprellung <strong>(S06.9)</strong></label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="dcontainer">
                            <img src="{{asset('img/Oberschenkelfraktur.png')}}" alt="KI Portfolio" width="150" height="150">
                            <br>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" class="postreq" value="3" name="icdcount"> Oberschenkelfraktur <strong>(S72.9)</strong></label>
                        </div>

                        <!-- <label><input type="checkbox" class="postreq" value="2" name="icdcount"> Schädel-Hirn-Trauma<strong> (S20.2)</strong></label><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/119/119044.svg" width="150" height="150"> -->
                        <!-- <label><input type="checkbox" class="postreq" value="1" name="icdcount"> Handgelenksprellung <strong>(S06.9)</strong></label><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/119/119044.svg" width="150" height="150"> -->
                        <!-- <label><input type="checkbox" class="postreq" value="3" name="icdcount"> Oberschenkelfraktur <strong>(S72.9)</strong></label><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/119/119044.svg" width="150" height="150"> -->
                        <br>

                        <div class="dcontainer">
                            <img src="{{asset('img/Schlüsselbeinfraktur.png')}}" alt="KI Portfolio" width="150" height="150">
                            <br>

                            <label><input type="checkbox" class="postreq" value="3" name="icdcount"> Schlüsselbeinfraktur <strong>(S42.00)</strong></label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="dcontainer">
                            <img src="{{asset('img/knie.png')}}" alt="KI Portfolio" width="150" height="150">
                            <br>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" class="postreq" value="1" name="icdcount"> Offene Wunde des Knies <strong>(S81.0)</strong></label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="container">
                            <img src="{{asset('img/zerrung.png')}}" alt="KI Portfolio" width="150" height="150">
                            <br>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" class="postreq" value="1" name="icdcount"> Verstauchung und Zerrung des Schultergelenkes<strong> (S43.4)</strong>                            
                        </div>

                        <!-- <label><input type="checkbox" class="postreq" value="3" name="icdcount"> Schlüsselbeinfraktur <strong>(S42.00)</strong></label><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/119/119044.svg" width="150" height="150"> -->
                        <!-- <label><input type="checkbox" class="postreq" value="1" name="icdcount"> Offene Wunde des Knies <strong>(S81.0)</strong></label><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/119/119044.svg" width="150" height="150"> -->
                        <!-- <label><input type="checkbox" class="postreq" value="1" name="icdcount"> Verstauchung und Zerrung des Schultergelenkes<strong> (S43.4)</strong></label><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/119/119044.svg" width="150" height="150"> -->

                    </div>






                    <br>

                    <div>

                        <input type="hidden" placeholder="input" value="0" name="s13_4_only" id="s13hidden" />
                    </div>


                    <br>

                   <font size="8"> <span id="slider_value2" style="color:red;font-weight:bold;"></span>€<br></font>

                    80€ - 5000€ <input type="range" min="0" max="5000" step="50" name="sld6" value="477" onchange="show_value2(this.value)">




                </div>

                <button type="submit">Schmerzensgeld berechnen</button>






            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $(".postreq").on("change", function() {

            let mcmax = 0;
            let s13_4_only = false;
            if ($(".postreq:checked").length === 1) {
                s13_4_only = $("#s13_4_only:checked").length === 1;


            }
            console.log($("#s13_4_only"));

            $("#s13hidden").val(s13_4_only !== false ? 1 : 0);




            $.each($("input[name='icdcount']:checked"), function() {
                let val = $(this).val();
                if (val > mcmax) {
                    mcmax = val;
                }
            });
            $("#mcmax").val(mcmax);
        })
    });





    function show_value2(x) {
        document.getElementById("slider_value2").innerHTML = x;
    }
</script>
```

I just want that the pictures you see in the screenshot are in a 3x3 order directly put together. I don't know which css code it is, but it breaks the order and pushes everything out of the layout.(below is my code of layouts.ap.blade)

Somehow some checkboxes are even not clickable.

```
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    @yield('head')

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Choose specific title -->
    <title> @yield('title')</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.min.css">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>


    <!-- App.js for Vue Templates -->
    <script defer src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- CSRF -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <style>
        html,

        body {
            background-color: coral;
            color: #636b6f;
            font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 200;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .full-height {
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .flex-center {
            align-items: center;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .position-ref {
            position: relative;
        }

        .top-right {
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            top: 18px;
        }

        .content {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .title {
            font-size: 84px;
        }

        .links>a {
            color: #636b6f;
            padding: 0 25px;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: 600;
            letter-spacing: .1rem;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .m-b-md {
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        img.one {
            height: 20.6%;
            width: 20.6%;
        }


    </style>
</head>

<body>

    @section('sidebar')
    <!-- defines a section of content: sidebar => @show -->
    @show
    <div id="app">
        <topbar></topbar>

        @yield('content')

        <!-- used to display the contents of given section -->

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I am using Laravel together with its blade syntax, so I can inherit specific some attributes. Could someone tell me where I can write down the css in order to get my structure back? I'll show it in my screenshot down below.

Answer (score 0):

Dear questionsaboutmycode;

Firstly my advice, you need to learn responsive design for your front end for fixing images heights, or layouts, form elements etc.

You can have a look this document:

[W3Schools Responsive Design](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp)

This information can help you a lot for your design.

Also the easiest way for doing 3x3 image design, you can use css libraries for this situation.

Most usefull css libraries:
[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)
[Materialize](https://materializecss.com/)
[MDBootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/)

For your problem, you can check the layouts section for odd the libraries.

Best regards.